# Call method in class that passes parameter to a stored procedure in DAL method

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, methods, parameters

I have two classes `Program.cs` and `DataAccessLayer.cs`.

I have a stored procedure that "lives" in the `DataAccessLayer`.

What I am trying to do is when the `Program.cs` runs, I need it to pass TWO parameters (`@Department1` and `@Department2`) to the stored procedure in the DAL.

Once I call the DAL method in the `Program`, I need to store the stored procedure results in a file. I understand that I will have to call the DAL method twice (once for Dept1, a second time for Dept2).

My question is: how do I format the Program method to pass the parameter for Dept1, and then store those results in an Excel file?

I'm assuming once I get the method in the Program class for Dept1, I can just copy and paste it for Dept2 and then just change the parameter (@Department2) that needs to be passed.

I am not worried about the @StartDate/@EndDate parameters since those don't change with each run of the stored procedure.

It should be noted that my variable (@DepartmentID) is a static variable in the stored procedure.

Basically what this stored procedure is designed to do is take the parameter of Dept1, return results that the app will put in a file.

Then I call the method in question again, this time with Dept2 Parameter, and return those results. Hope this made sense...

This is what I have in the DAL currently...

```
public bool GetDeptData(SqlConnection Conn, string StartDate,string EndDate, out DataTable DTDepartmentData)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime();

    SqlDbType DepartmentID = new SqlDbType();
    DTDepartmentData = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        // Set our start date and end date for last month
        startDate = DateTime.Parse(
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Year.ToString() + "-" +
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString() + "-01 00:00:00");
        endDate = DateTime.Parse(
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Year.ToString() + "-" +
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString() + "-" +
            DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Year,  DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month) + " 23:59:59");



        // Call our stored procedure and populate the datatable with the Dept data
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_EXAMPLESP", Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "departmentID"; 
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(DTDepartmentData);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception CaughtError)
    {
        this.ErrorMsg = "An error occurred in the GetDeptData method: " + CaughtError.ToString() + " || " + Environment.NewLine;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You are not receiving the value for DepartmentId to search for in your DAL method. You should pass it from the Program.cs. Instead you shouldn't pass the SqlConnection. This object belongs to the DAL layer where it will be instanced when needed and destroyed immediately after usage.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what issue you are facing with this code. So by looking at your code I think you should Change `GetDeptData` method to accept one more parameter `departmentId` and pass value of that parameter from program.cs.

Comment: Hello there Chetan, thank you for the response. I don't have problems with this code specifically, rather - I was asking how I should code the program class to pass the DepartmentID parameter to this class and the stored procedure therein. Shouldn't the following code in the method accept a parameter from another class (in this case, the Program.cs) "cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "departmentID";"

Comment: Long story short - Im basically asking "What code do I need to include in my program class in order to pass the departmentID parameter to the DAL method that has a stored procedure in it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the value of *departmentID* from main to your DAL method start changing the signature of the GetDeptData method to this one

```
public bool GetDeptData(string StartDate,string EndDate, string deptId, out DataTable DTDepartmentData)
{

     // The SqlConnection should be created here and destroyed 
     // here, everytime you call this method

     using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....connectionstring....))
     {
        // then use the deptId value in the creation 
        // of the parameter @DepartmentId
       .....
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = deptId; 
       adapter.Fill(DTDepartmentData);
       return true;

    }
 }
 catch(Exception ....)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Now in your Program.cs you should create an instance of your DAL class and call the method passing the values required

```
 DataTable dtResult = null;
 string startDate = SomeCodeToGetTheStartDate();
 string endDate = SomeCodeToGetTheEndDate();
 string deptId = SomeCodeToGetTheDeptId();
 MyDALClass cs = new MyDALClass();
 if(cs.GetDeptData(startDate, endDate, deptId, out dtResult)
     .... success ....
```

Side note: Are you sure that the departmentId is a string value and not an integer?

Comment: Wow this is super helpful. And yes, the dept ID is an integer, sorry. I just listed it as a string for example purposes. So if im understanding this correctly - the top block of code is what I should use in my DAL, and then the bottom block of code is what I should use in my main program class?

Comment: Yes, more or less. The first block of code is a partial rewrite of the GetDepData in the DAL class (whatever is the real name of the class). The second block should go inside the Program.cs and mainly consist in getting the user input for dates and department. Then just create the DAL class (using its real name) and calling the method GetDeptData.

Comment: Change the _string deptId_ to _int deptId_ and modify the SqlDbType to Int.